# What is a difference between a correspondence and a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

What is a difference between a correspondence and a function. For example I give the following definition of a correspondence that takes a value is a space $T$ that denotes the space of private information to the space $E$ that gives a code say an integer number that is unique for every $t\in T$. Namely, $C:T\to E$ such that
$$C(t)=\{e\in E|t\in e\},\quad\text{$\forall t\in T$}$$

I can not understand what is the difference from a function. Could anyone give his help for understanding this?

Comment: In math a "correspondence" is a [Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)). A *function* is a special type of relation.

Comment: It is like we say "a corresponden is a function but the inverse does not alwyas hold?"

Comment: No.  As the duplicate makes clear, a correspondence might be multi-valued, in which case it would not be a function.  Study the duplicate.

Comment: @lulu I saw it, but it is not exaclty helping to me...this is why I gave an example that I found. So as someone could respond something on this exapmle....Nevermind I will check it more

Comment: Your example is hard to follow as there are a lot of undefined terms (like "space of private information").  If, in your example, $C(t)$ is always a single value $e\in E$, then that is indeed a function.  But of course every function is also a correspondence.  That doesn't change the fact that there are some correspondences which are not functions.

Comment: @lulu ok now it's more clear. So, you say "there are some correspondences which are not functions". Any example?

Comment: The correspondence between birthdays and people.  As there are many people with a given birthday, this is not a function between dates and individuals.

Comment: $C$ is not defined for $t\not\in E$ and may have more than one value $e$ for $t\in E$. A function from $T$ to $E$ must assign exactly one value to each $t\in T$.